# Draw image over phone case mold in Android

Tags: android, templates, canvas, bitmap, draw

I have different templates of smartphone cases in SVG file and i am trying to do a custom case with an image that the user will select.

How can i achieve this? I have tried using canvas with no luck.
Thanks.